# How can I move files between folders and subfolders using a Windows script?

Tags: windows, file-management, cmd.exe

I am moving .jpg files from a directory and its subdirectories on a daily basis and then deleting them. To make this easier I created 2 batch files: One that moves the files and one that deletes them.

To move the files:

```
move C:\"DIRECTORY\*.jpg C:\temp\
move C:\"DIRECTORY\SUBDIRECTORY\*.jpg C:\temp\
move C:\"DIRECTORY\SUBDIRECTORY2\*.jpg C:\temp\
move C:\"DIRECTORY\SUBDIRECTORY3\*.jpg C:\temp\
```

And to delete files:

```
del C:\temp\*.jpg
```

Can I create one script that looks for the files under the folder and subfolders (new subfolders are created regularly) that can do both?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. Are you doing something in between moving the .JPGs to Temp and deleting them? If not, why not simply delete them instead of moving and *then* deleting? Here's a command that will do just that:

```
for /r "Drive:\Path to\source folder" %f in (*.jpg) do @del "%f"
```

If you want to do it in two steps with other actions in between, use this:

```
for /r "Drive:\Path to\source folder" %f in (*.jpg) do @move "%f" "Drive:\Path to\destination folder"
REM Do something else here
del "Drive:\Path to\destination folder\*.jpg"
```